# Solving a 3rd order differential equation with a non constant coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I am trying to solve this non linear differential equation with 3 boundary conditions :

$$ R\dfrac{d^3 h}{d R^3}+2\dfrac{d^2 h}{d R^2}  + k\dfrac{d h}{d R} = 0$$

With : $\frac{d h}{d R}(R=0)=0$, $h(R=L) = \frac{d h}{d R}(R=L)=0$

Unfortunately, I am stuck because I haven't been able to find a reliable way to solve it correctly.

How do you think it would be possible to find an analytical solution to this equation ?

Thank you,

Cheers.

Comment: Let $dh/dR=y(R)$ then you have a second order equation for $y$, which results in Bessel's equation for $g(t)$ upon changing variables $R=t^2/4k$ and $y=g/t$. Then $g(t)=A J_1(t)+BY_1(t)$. Substitute back to find eventually $h'(R)$ then integrate it to find $h(R)=AJ_0(2\sqrt{kR})+BY_0(2\sqrt{kR})+C$. Find the integration constants by applying the boundary conditions...

Comment: Obviously, $h=0$ is a solution. It is not certain that non-trivial solutions exist. You might need special values for $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have derivatives of $h$ of orders $1$, $2$, and $3$ (but not $0$, namely $h$ itself), we can make the substitution $y = \frac{dh}{dR}$, resulting in the second-order linear equation in $y$:
$$
R\, \frac{d^2 y}{dR^2} + 2\, \frac{dy}{dR} + k\, y = 0.
$$
We can multiply through by $R$, yielding:
$$
R^2\, \frac{d^2 y}{dR^2} + 2R\, \frac{dy}{dR} + kR\, y = 0.
$$
Now the first two terms are a derivative of a product:
$$
\frac{d}{dR} \biggl( R^2\, \frac{d y}{dR} \biggr) + kR\, y = 0.
$$
This is the standard form for a (homogeneous) [Sturm–Liouville equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory). There is a robust theory for studying solutions to equations of this form, however you're probably not going to see an analytic solution *in a closed form* unless you're willing to use Bessel functions and other special functions.

You can, of course, find a series solution, starting with the assumption that
$$
y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n R^n, 
$$
and using the differential equation in its original form to determine recurrence relations among the coefficients (and use the boundary values to get initial values).